# Solving a system of non-autonomous, linear, homogeneous first-order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a system of linear non-autonomous, linear, homogeneous equations:
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}(t) \\
\dot{y}(t) 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & e^{-i b t} \\
e^{i b t} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\
y(t) 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with initial conditions $x(0) = x_{0}$ and $y(0) = y_{0}$.
I am able to easily get an analytic solution for this system via Wolfram Mathematica, however I would like to be able to reproduce this result with pen and paper but I am at a loss for the approach.

My first thought was to try solving using the matrix exponential:
$$\mathbf{X}(t) = \exp\left(\int_{0}^{t}\mathbf{A}(\tau) \ {\rm{d}}\tau\right)\mathbf{X}(0) \text{,}$$
however this does not work because (as I later realised) this approach works only if $\mathbf{A}(t)$ commutes for different times. I have also flirted with the time-ordered exponential approach (borrowing from Quantum Mechanics), but this does not replicate my Mathematica result (which I trust).

Comment: This question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange

Comment: On hindsight you are probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $X(t) = \exp(ibt)x(t)$. Then

$$ \dot{X}(t) = ib X(t) + \exp(ibt)\dot{x}(t) = ib X(t) + a X(t) + y(t) $$

and

$$ \dot{y}(t) = X(t) $$

So the system now solves

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \dot{X}(t) \\ 
\dot{y}(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a + ib & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X(t) \\ y(t) \end{bmatrix}$$

which is an autonomous system.

Comment: I am stupid. Thanks.